# Transparent Menu Bar with Revolution Slider

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

X theme by themeco, and Revolution slider I am trying to make the menu bar transparent with the slider so that the bottom of the slider is the background of the menu bar. If I remove the background color of the menu bar I'm left with it being transparent with the background color of the site which is white. So I'm guessing I want to know how to move it up so that its transparent with the slider. Here is the link to the site below.
http://www.superherodigital.com/thehonestelite/

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

Heres the CSS you'll need to update...

```
.x-navbar{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.x-navbar-wrap{
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.tp-bullets.hidebullets{
    bottom:60px;
}
```

The `.tp-bullets.hidebullets` class moves the slider bullets up from behind the menu.